# PhoneGap 2.2 is not find any html file other than index.html

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Am using PhoneGap 2.2 and XCode-4.

Setting up the PhoneGap is successful.
Followed : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

when i set the startPage = @"test.html", PhoneGap is not finding test.html instead its trying to open index.html. I tried restarting XCode since PhoneGap 2.2 is not perfectly working in XCode-4.

Comment: did you set the folder correctly? viewController.wwwFolderName = @"myfolder"; is the test.html there?

Comment: issue not there in wwwFolderName. If i rename test.html to index.html. It work's well. Its not working with any other name. Looks like PhoneGap hardcoded to index.html.

Comment: I doubt they hard coded it, I know it works with 1.9, but I don´t think they just change it. Doesnt make too much sense too me. When you change it to index.html, your file name is also index.html? It´s odd anyway.